# Open and close divs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a **comment system** for my webpage.
The website shows a group of elements from the database, that everyone can comment:

Element 1 ($element_id=1)-> Read comments...

Element 2 ($element_id=2)-> Read comments...

Element 3 ($element_id=3)-> Read comments...

When someone want to read comments of one element, can click in the "Read comments...", and a new div opens:

```
<div class="comments_more" id="comments_more"> Read comments...
<div class="comments_div" id="comments_div" > 
<?php include/comments.php ?>
<?php echo $element_id; ?>
</div> </div>
```

The jquery code to open the div works perfect for every element:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( '.comments_more' ).click(function() {
    $(this).find( '#comments_div' ).show('slide');
    });
    })
```

Now, I found a nice jquery to close the div when user clicks outside of it:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
var container = $("#comments_div");
if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{        container.hide();    }
});
```

**The problem** is that it **only works for the first** "Read comments..." (first element).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can multiple different HTML elements have the same ID if they're different elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple IDs on one page, try using a *class* as a *selector* instead like:

```
$(".comments_div")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here at what the repeated HTML looks like, but try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.comments_more').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.comments_div').show('slide');
  });
})

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $(".comments_div");
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
  {
    container.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.comments_div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comments_more"> Read comments...
  <div class="comments_div">
    Comments 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comments_more"> Read comments...
  <div class="comments_div">
    Comments 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comments_more"> Read comments...
  <div class="comments_div">
    Comments 3
  </div>
</div>
```